# Can't connect to Firebird 3.0 with user with small letters in login with Java

Tags: java, firebird, firebird-3.0, jaybird

I connect with names in capital letters, but it does not want to connect with small letters in the login.

Here is a small test

```
String ENCODING = "WIN1251";
String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:C:/ProgramData/test.FDB";
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("encoding", ENCODING);
properties.setProperty("roleName", "GUEST");
properties.setProperty("user", "smoll2");
properties.setProperty("password", "1234567a");
DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL, properties);
```

```
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Your user name and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login. [SQLState:28000, ISC error code:335544472]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$4.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:572)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:302)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:138)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:202)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readOperationResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:161)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version13.V13WireOperations.authReceiveResponse(V13WireOperations.java:122)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.authReceiveResponse(V10Database.java:569)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.WireConnection.identify(WireConnection.java:309)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.performConnect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:51)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:39)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:32)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:141)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:550)
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:124)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:137)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
```

Comment: Maybe the user in the database onl yhas uppercase letters? You will have to create a new user or rename the existing one to lower case.

Comment: No. I can have as many users as I want. But it is not possible to connect with small letters in the login. I thought maybe the translation to uppercase was done before me. As FireBird 2 the register was not important. But I have a new driver and just a few lines of code

Comment: FB 3 has two "authentication plugins", LEGACY and SRP.  LEGACY is extracted FB1/2 code, and SRP is "new, proper" one. Try reading about it and maybe change the FB config to only allow legacy and not any other. If then the case sensitivity would be back to FB2 case, then perhaps that is where the diffference comes from.  // You might try community at https://sqlru.net  or maybe try old articles of sql.ru from on web.archive.org

Comment: Please show the output (using SYSDBA or another admin user) for `select sec$user_name, sec$active, sec$plugin from sec$users;`

Comment: @knittl All-uppercase usernames are case-insensitive in Firebird. But using unquoted usernames results in them being converted to uppercase (so authenticating with `smoll2` authenticates against user `SMOLL2`). The problem is either that the user was created case-sensitively (in which case the OP needs to authenticate as `"smoll2"` (i.e. string literal `"\"smoll2\""`), or that the user was created with the Legacy_UserManager, and Jaybird 4 and higher do not try Legacy_Auth by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically four situations where this authentication error will happen:

1. The user does not exist or has the wrong password
2. You created the user with a case-sensitive username, e.g. using `CREATE USER "smoll2" ...`.
3. You created the user with the Legacy_UserManager, and are using Jaybird 4, which by default [no longer authenticates with Legacy_Auth](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/4.0.x/release_notes.html#default-authentication-plugins)
4. The user is marked inactive

I assume case 1 doesn't apply here, but otherwise you need to create the user or change its password.

For case 2, it is important to realise that - since Firebird 3.0 - usernames are identifiers, and follow the same rules as identifiers. Which means unquoted names are stored in uppercase, and match case-insensitively (by means of uppercasing), while quoted names are stored exactly and are compared as is. If you created the user case-sensitively (`CREATE USER "smoll2" ...`), then you need to authenticate with a quoted user name:

```java
properties.setProperty("user", "\"smoll2\"");
```

If you don't do this, you are actually authenticating against the user SMOLL2 (which doesn't exist).

For case 3, since Firebird 3.0, Firebird provides multiple authentication plugins with accompanying user managers. Users exist per user manager. Since Jaybird 4, Jaybird by default only authenticates with plugins Srp256 and Srp (which share the Srp user manager). If you created your user with the Legacy_UserManager (either because it is the first configured in `UserManager` in firebird.conf, or because you used the `using plugin Legacy_UserManager` clause when creating the user), you cannot authenticate with the default settings of Jaybird, because it doesn't try the Legacy_Auth user plugin.

There are two solutions for this case:

1. Drop the user with the Legacy_UserManager and create it with the Srp user manager
2. Configure Jaybird to also try Legacy_Auth:

   ```java
   properties.setProperty("authPlugins", "Srp256,Srp,Legacy_Auth");
   ```

   If you only want to try Legacy_Auth, you can remove Srp256 and Srp from the list.

As a variation of case 3, this can also occur if you have a custom user manager and authentication plugin which is not supported by Jaybird.

Finally case 4, a user can be inactive (either because it was created with the `INACTIVE` clause, or altered to inactive). An inactive user is not allowed to authenticate. The inactive state is ignored for Legacy_UserManager/Legacy_Auth. If a user is inactive, you can activate it again with:

```sql
alter user smoll2 set active
```

Be aware that it could also be a combination of 2 and 3 (using a case-sensitive username **and** Legacy_UserManager). You can verify which user you have, if it is active, and for which user manager, by executing the following query as SYSDBA or a user with RDB$ADMIN role in the current database and the security database:

```sql
select sec$user_name, sec$active, sec$plugin from sec$users;
```

For Legacy_UserManager, the `SEC$ACTIVE` column is NULL, as it doesn't support the active/inactive state.